# How to fix Android Studio emulator failing to launch?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-emulator, build.gradle

TLDR - Android Studio will not load the emulator and says the cloud operation was unsuccessful along with this error message:

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.
```

Android studio version:

```
**Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034, built on November 20, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin**
```

To start, I clicked run to start the Pixel 5 API 26 emulator and run my application, and my computer blue screened with the error KMOD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED, and the file that failed was IntelHaxm.sys.

Once rebooted, I try again, and Android studio gives a different error that I did not copy down -- something about a corrupted file. When I started Googling, the only thing I found was to delete the .gradle file and let it be rebuilt. When I tried again, I got the error mentioned at the start. Same results after invalidating cache and restarting.

The only difference between it working a few days ago and now is a computer restart, and I installed CPU-Z which I have already uninstalled, and I installed HWMonitor to look at CPU temp.

Here is the rest of the build log:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\School\Capstone\Module 8\NewProject

AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 32\n\nThis Android Gradle plugin (7.0.4) was tested up to compileSdk = 31\n\nThis warning can be suppressed by adding\n    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=32\nto this project's gradle.properties\n\nThe build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to\nuse a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 32","sources":[{}]}
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 9s
22 actionable tasks: 22 executed
```

Edit: It works on my laptop with the same files (they sync over OneDrive)

Comment: Install HAXM ...and don't ignore prominent warnings.

Comment: No need to be condescending. Nothing in the warning says install haxm, it worked 2 days ago, and I don't even know what haxm is. I'll try REinstalling and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was VT-x was disabled in BIOS. I forgot my bios updated, and a setting must have been reset.